# Java with OLE Outlook on Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ole, outlook-2007

I'm currently trying to set up a module in my Java application to send scheduled emails (specifically jasper reports) using MS Outlook 2007, I found this tutorial for eclipse http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMicrosoftIntegration/article.html and I downloaded the referenced libraries (swt.jar swt-debug.jar and org.eclipse.core.commands.jar for x64bits) and added them to my Netbeans project classpath.
I copied the code from that page to give it a try

```
public class SendMail{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SendMail outlook = new SendMail();
        try {
            outlook.execute();
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SendMail.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public Object execute() throws ExecutionException {
        Display display = Display.getCurrent();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
        // This should start outlook if it is not running yet
        OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "OVCtl.OVCtl");
        site.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE); 
        // now get the outlook application
        OleClientSite site2 = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE,
                "Outlook.Application");
        OleAutomation outlook = new OleAutomation(site2);
        // 
        OleAutomation mail = invoke(outlook, "CreateItem", 0 /* Mail item */)
                .getAutomation();
        setProperty(mail, "To", "my@email.com"); /*
         * Empty but could also be
         * predefined
         */

        setProperty(mail, "Bcc", "my@email.com"); /*
         * Empty but could also be
         * predefined
         */

        setProperty(mail, "BodyFormat", 2 /* HTML */);
        setProperty(mail, "Subject", "Top News for you");
        setProperty(mail, "HtmlBody",
                "<html>Hello<p>, please find some infos here.</html>");
        File file = new File("c:/temp/test.txt");
        if (file.exists()) {
            OleAutomation attachments = getProperty(mail, "Attachments");
            invoke(attachments, "Add", "c:/temp/test.txt");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Info.",
                    "Attachment not found; will send email with attachment", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        }
        invoke(mail, "Display" /* or "Send" */);
        return null;
    }

    private static OleAutomation getProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name) {
        Variant varResult = auto.getProperty(property(auto, name));
        if (varResult != null && varResult.getType() != OLE.VT_EMPTY) {
            OleAutomation result = varResult.getAutomation();
            varResult.dispose();
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command,
            String value) {
        return auto.invoke(property(auto, command),
                new Variant[]{new Variant(value)});
    }

    private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command) {
        return auto.invoke(property(auto, command));
    }

    private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command, int value) {
        return auto.invoke(property(auto, command),
                new Variant[]{new Variant(value)});
    }

    private static boolean setProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name,
            String value) {
        return auto.setProperty(property(auto, name), new Variant(value));
    }

    private static boolean setProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name,
            int value) {
        return auto.setProperty(property(auto, name), new Variant(value));
    }

    private static int property(OleAutomation auto, String name) {
        return auto.getIDsOfNames(new String[]{name})[0];
    }
}
```

But it shows the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to create Ole Client. result = -2147221164
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(OLE.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite.<init>(OleClientSite.java:242)
    at tutorialjavamail.SendMail.execute(SendMail.java:44)
    at tutorialjavamail.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

I'm new handling emails on java, but I've already looked up JavaMail, but apparently it doesn't go well with Microsoft Exchange Servers.

Comment: What line of code exactly fires the exception?

Comment: The `OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "OVCtl.OVCtl");` one, I think my problem is that I can't find that progID, and I've read somewhere that it starts the process on the server side, not as an Outlook client (where I will be running the code under), I just can't find the progID for Outlook 2007, even on regedit

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however I'm actually trying to access the client-side, from a client computer (read as, I just want to open the client Outlook in the local machine and send a mail through there).